# Unable to export all the data from Share Point list

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, custom-list, sharepoint-server, excel-services, export

In my Share Point list has 23072 records, but I am able to exports only 2000 records.

It has multivalued, Lookup, Yes/No & Calculated type columns and around 64 columns are there.

Any ideas, How to export all the data into excel sheet?

Thanks for any responses in advance!

Comment: Can you open the list in Datasheet View, and copy everything to Excel?

Answer (score 1):

Below PowerShell script will create different  .csv files for all the existing lists in web. , Hope this will be useful.

```
  Param(
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
     [string]$webUrl,
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
     [string]$outPath
    )

  Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell"
    $web = Get-SPWeb $webUrl
    write-host ("Path: " + $outPath)
    foreach($list in $web.Lists)
    {
      $exportlist = $null
      $exportlist = @()
      $list.Items | foreach {
        $hash = $null
        $hash = @{}
        foreach($fld in $_.Fields ){
          Try {
            $hash.add($fld.Title, $_[$fld.Title])
          }
          Catch [System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException]
          {
            # Eating an error caused by duplicate column names.
          }
          Finally
          {
            #"End"
          }
        }
        write-host ("Exported: " + $_.Title)
        $obj = New-Object PSObject -Property $hash #@{
        $exportlist += $obj

      }
      $expath = $outPath + '\' + $list.Title + '.csv'
      $exportlist | Export-Csv -path $expath #$oPath

    }
```